# How do i format a rest api

Tags: php, rest, pdo

I have a very basic RESTful api running on my localhost, and it looks something like this:

http://prntscr.com/nd8kpn

or in text:

```
{"course_id":"1",
"course_creator_id":"1",
"course_name":"Chanel Introduction",
"course_description":"In this course i will discuss info about myself and what you will be learning on my Chanel.",
"course_thumbnail":"\/public\/course_images\/0.jpg",
"date_added":"2019-04-17 15:25:39"
}
{"course_id":"2",
"course_creator_id":"1",
"course_name":"Getting started with Web Develop",
"course_description":"In this course, you will learn the basic concepts of Web Development. ",
"course_thumbnail":"\/public\/course_images\/1.jpg",
"date_added":"2019-04-17 15:25:39"
}
{"course_id":"3",
"course_creator_id":"1",
"course_name":"HTML and CSS Introduction",
"course_description":"In this course, I will go in depth on HTML, CSS and front end development of basic static webpages.",
"course_thumbnail":"\/public\/course_images\/2.jpg",
"date_added":"2019-04-17 15:25:39"
}
{"course_id":"4","course_creator_id":"1","course_name":"JavaScript and React Basics.","course_description":"In this course, we will dive deep into JavaScript and briefly go over the basics of React","course_thumbnail":"\/public\/course_images\/3.jpg","date_added":"2019-04-17 15:25:39"}
{"course_id":"5","course_creator_id":"1","course_name":"Building REST apis with Node and Express","course_description":"In this course, we will go in depth on REST apis and build one in the second half of the course.","course_thumbnail":"\/public\/course_images\/4.jpg","date_added":"2019-04-17 15:25:39"}
{"course_id":"6","course_creator_id":"1","course_name":"Building an e-books website from scratch","course_description":"In this course we will build an e-books website and combine everything from the previus 5 tutorials.","course_thumbnail":"\/public\/course_images\/5.jpg","date_added":"2019-04-17 15:25:39"}
{"course_id":"7","course_creator_id":"3","course_name":"What is Game Development","course_description":"In-depth look on game development (theory only, no code).","course_thumbnail":"\/public\/course_images\/6.jpg","date_added":"2019-04-17 15:25:39"}
{"course_id":"8","course_creator_id":"3","course_name":"C++ For Game Development","course_description":"In this massive course, i will teach you everything about C++ and touch on concepts for game development in C++.","course_thumbnail":"\/public\/course_images\/7.jpg","date_added":"2019-04-17 15:25:39"}
{"course_id":"9","course_creator_id":"3","course_name":"Introduction to Unreal Engine 4 ","course_description":"Here we will combine what you learnt in the previus course with Unreal Engine4 and start developing small games","course_thumbnail":"\/public\/course_images\/8.jpg","date_added":"2019-04-17 15:25:39"}
{"course_id":"10","course_creator_id":"3","course_name":"Making a turn based RPG with UE4 and C++","course_description":"In this tutorial, we will combined the previus 2 courses and make a turn based RPG from scratch","course_thumbnail":"\/public\/course_images\/9.jpg","date_added":"2019-04-17 15:25:39"}
```

My code is as follows:

```
include('../connect.php');
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM courses');
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach($result as $row){

    if(isset($_GET['course_id'])){
        if($row->course_id == $_GET['course_id']){
            echo json_encode($row);
        }
    } else if (isset($_GET['creator_id'])){
        if($row->course_creator_id == $_GET['creator_id']){
            echo json_encode($row);
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode($row);
    }

}
```

As i said, very simple. Im using it as a testing api rather then as a production one.

My question is, why are most REST api's so pretty like the facebook graph thing but my rest APIs always have an ugly format? How do i make my REST api pretty? :D

Comment: Hi, Please post text as text and not as pictures of text

Comment: Are you maybe jut looking for `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`?

Comment: Thanks, and then format it, or at least add 4 spaces to the beginning so it goes into a code block

Comment: @Dharman is that a header i need to include or a function i need to wrap my response in?

Comment: It is a constant to you use as a second parameter in `json_encode`

Comment: It's an API - it's not really meant to be read by people so it *shouldn't* make any difference whether it's pretty or not (arguably ugly is better as there are fewer bytes being transferred).

Comment: Wow. Well i guess im stupid xD ive been stressing over this for 2 months thinking im doing something wrong LOOL

Comment: _Small Point_ But thats not valid JSON ?

Comment: @CD001 I think it is better if it is well formatted since if you work with someone else, it will be easier for them ti see what exactly the response is without looking at the code (you know how front-end guys are)

Comment: Not quite sure what you are doing here but any code that changes the returned row contents to somehting else, smells fishy. I think you might benefit from checking the output against what you think you were trying to do here

Comment: @RiggsFolly as i said before, it is really just for testing purposes and nothing else.

Comment: :) But I thought the purpose of testing was to get things right

Comment: @RiggsFolly I guess we have different definitions :) I just want to put all the data out to the browser first before i do anything to it and then call the data from my react app with axios. Once i get the data into react i will go back into php and start doing stuff to it

Comment: Check @hakan-sonmez answer. At least if you do that your react app stands a better chance of understanding the JSON when you get it that far

Comment: I know that what I wrote will not return a valid json response, I know I have to push each $row object onto an array and then print it. That was not my question here.  Thanks for the tips tho. Also I upvoted @hakan's answer so anyone viewing this question will see that I didn't output the data in a valid json format.

Comment: If my answer is correct, you should accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to create a valid json output then you need to declare your output is a json like followings;

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include('../connect.php');
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM courses');
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$rows = [];
foreach($result as $row){
    if(isset($_GET['course_id'])){
        if($row->course_id == $_GET['course_id']){
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
    } else if (isset($_GET['creator_id'])){
        if($row->course_creator_id == $_GET['creator_id']){
             $rows[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
         $rows[] = $row;
    }
}
echo json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

JSON_PRETTY_PRINT is responsible for printing the data in rows and not in a single line